# How to return the full URL before the hash (using php)?

Tags: php, substring

The question basically covers it. I'm sure this question has been asked, but I can't seem to find it.

Just to be clear, I have this url

`https://www.example.com/page.php#!/more-and-more/text/that-needs-to-go/away`

and I'd like to return with this url

`https://www.example.com/page.php`

I think I'm supposed to use `substr` but alas, I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always sure that you will have a **#** in your url then

> explode() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

here what you need

```
 $url = 'https://www.example.com/page.php#!/more-and-more/text/that-needs-to-go/away';
 $temp = explode("#",$url);
 $url = $temp[0];
 echo $url;

// output - https://www.example.com/page.php
```

i think this may be helpful

Other than that you can do this

> substr() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
>
> strpos() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
 $url = 'https://www.example.com/page.php#!/more-and-more/text/that-needs-to-go/away';

 echo $url=substr($url,0,strpos($url,"#"));

 // output - https://www.example.com/page.php
```

//  this will also work

Comment: Woo! I got the `substr` part right haha. The second one was perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

$url = 'https://www.example.com/page.php#!/more-and-more/text/that-needs-to-go/away';
print_r(parse_url($url));

or

$pattern = '/.*page.php/';

preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same tag "#", you can do the following:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/page.php#!/more-and-more/text/that-needs-to-go/away';
echo strstr($url, '#', true);
```